# Send a file with SOAP DataHandler

Tags: java, soap, weblogic, jpeg, datahandler

I got a problem to send a JPEG image on datahandler on a web service. This issue seems to be only for JPEG files, not other types. Somehow when I try to send via the web service, the same method can't find the file and shows an *IOException*.

```
InputStream
  at com.hp.mps.onlinetransactions.actions.SikayetAction.generalErrorMessageForSrOperation(SikayetAction.java:477)
  at com.hp.mps.onlinetransactions.actions.SikayetAction.process(SikayetAction.java:248)
  at com.hp.mps.common.base.MPSBaseAction.execute(MPSBaseAction.java:708)
  at com.hp.mps.infrastructure.mvc.ControllingServlet.chainProcess(ControllingServlet.java:1000)
  at com.hp.mps.infrastructure.mvc.ControllingServlet.service(ControllingServlet.java:654)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
  at com.hp.mps.common.util.DoubleSubmitFilter.doFilter(DoubleSubmitFilter.java:86)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3748)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
  at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1499)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to encode the image to a stream ImageDataContentHandler requires Image object, was given object of type class java.io.FileInputStream
  at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.ImageDataContentHandler.writeTo(ImageDataContentHandler.java:174)
  at   .DataHandlerAttachment.writeTo(DataHandlerAttachment.java:122)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MimeCodec.encode(MimeCodec.java:155)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SwACodec.encode(SwACodec.java:57)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:261)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:189)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:124)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:118)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:866)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:815)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:778)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:680)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:272)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:153)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:115)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:95)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:136)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy427.saveFile(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:84)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy236.saveFile(Unknown Source)
  at com.hp.mps.onlinetransactions.beans.SikayetFileOperationsBean.saveFile(SikayetFileOperationsBean.java:66)
  at com.hp.mps.onlinetransactions.actions.SikayetAction.getDocIdFromFileServer(SikayetAction.java:317)
  at com.hp.mps.onlinetransactions.actions.SikayetAction.fillDocumentMap(SikayetAction.java:259)
  at com.hp.mps.onlinetransactions.actions.SikayetAction.process(SikayetAction.java:209)
  ... 20 more
```

Comment: Please add some details and code to better understand your question

Comment: *"Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to encode the image to a stream ImageDataContentHandler requires Image object, was given object of type class java.io.FileInputStream"* -- seems to be the problem right there?

Comment: (Type listed here: [`DataHandlerAttachment`](http://javadox.com/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.2.8/com/sun/xml/ws/message/DataHandlerAttachment.html) (`com.sun.xml.ws.message.DataHandlerAttachment`))